# How to use json with cakephp

Tags: json, cakephp-2.3

I am totaly lost with json and cakephp.
I am extracting data from a database

```
$this->loadModel('Config');
        $config = $this->Config->find('first',array(
                'fields' => array(
                            'sitename',
                            'sitestatus',
                            'siteadminemail',
                            'sitehomepage', // homepage
                            'poststatus',
                            'postrssstatus',
                            'mailusesmtp',
                            'mailsmtpuser',
                            'mailsmtppw',
                            'mailsmtpport',
                            'mailsmtphosts',
                            'mailsmtpauth',
                            'mailcharset',
                            'mailencoding',
                            'sociaddthis',
                            'socifacebook',
                            'socifacebookuser',
                            'socitwitter',
                            'socitwitteruser',
                            'socilinkedin',
                            'socilinkedinuser',
                            'socigoogle',
                            'socigoogleuser'
                            ),
                'conditions'=> array(
                    'id'=>1
                )
        ));
```

I would like to serialize is into a json form.
MY goal is to get one of those value somewhere in my cakephp application. For example in a layout, controller, model or view or component.

I saw some information about json . For exemple, I red I have to add this in my roote.php

```
Router::parseExtensions('rss','json');
```

I added json.
Then on my AppController I add 'RequestHandler' as a compnents.

```
 public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
             // For the ACL
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            ),
            'authError' => 'Pensiez-vous réellement que vous étiez autorisés à voir cela ?',
            // Mets des condition au niveau de la validation d'authentificate
            // Contient l'ensemble des methode d'authentification
            'authenticate' => array(
                // Mehtode Form est utilisée
                'Form' => array(
                    // Defini les paramêtre scope. Ici défini que le compte doit est actif
                    'scope'=> array('User.active' =>1)
                )
            )
        ), 
        'Session',
        'Ctrl',
        'RequestHandler' // Ajouté pour jSon

    );
```

But now, I have no idea how to serialize $configs and how to use one od the serialized json data.

Some of you have example, totu, help?

Many thank to all of you

Comment: did you check in this link  : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html ?

Comment: Yes I did, but I could not make my tasks working. I am new with this topics

Comment: Yes I did, but I could not make my tasks working. I am new with this topics. I think my need is a bit different. I not need to use a view. I would like to store data from the DB into a json format to use is in Layout, view, component, controllers etc. The data are the website setting, like Sitename, Sitestatus, Sitehomepage, Smtpstatus, etc

Answer (score 0):

Serialize object to work with it in your view makes no sense. Since you added a json-router it seems like you want to send the response to the client as a json object, and not work with it in a view file. 
In that case it's easy. In your controllers action, just do

```
public function getConfigAsJson() {
  $config = $this->Config->find('first', ...etc...);
  return new CakeResponse(array('body' => $config, 'type' => 'json'));
}
```

This won't require any view file at all. Great to use if you have a REST-service or want to use ajax calls from your client to the server.